# Edit SFTP PDF file in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, mpdf

I tried using the code below to edit sftp a pdf file. but I could not do it.

```
<?php

use Mpdf\Mpdf;
use Storage;

public function index()
{
    $mpdf = new Mpdf();
    $path = 'company/5bc03ec25b559.pdf'; // file path
    $view = Storage::disk('sftp')->get($path);

    $mpdf->SetImportUse();
    $pagecount = $mpdf->SetSourceFile($view);
    $tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage($pagecount);
    $mpdf->UseTemplate($tplId);
        //enter code here
        $mpdf->SetAlpha(0.8);
        $mpdf->Image(public_path() . "/images/favicon.gif", 160, 10, 30, 20, 'gif', '', true, false);
        $mpdf->SetAlpha(1);
        return $mpdf->Output();
 }
```

How do I set SFTP URL file path `SetSourceFile()` function. I need to know how to apply the `Storage::disk('sftp')` file path in SetSourceFile().

Comment: Use league/flysystem ?

Answer (score 0):

`$mpdf->SetSourceFile` accepts a path to file, rather than the file contents as you are passing.

I guess you'd need to download the template PDF file from the SFTP to a local copy, and make changes using mPDF to the local file.

```
file_put_contents($localPath, Storage::disk('sftp')->get($path));
$mpdf->setSourceFile($localPath);

// ...

$mpdf->Output();
```